# how to pause a audio on click a video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've made a jquery script to pause the background music on click a video but it don't work. Can anyone help me?Here's my javascript:

```
<script src="../style/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
     function(){
         $("#trailer").click(
             function(){
                 $("#bgm").get(0).pause();
                }
            )
        }
    );
</script>
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<video height="340" width="864.5" id="trailer" onclick="goFullscreen('trailer');">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<embed src="sound.mp3" hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="true" id="bgm"></embed>
```

Anyway, my embed mp3 can't loop too, can anyone correct it for me?THKS.

Comment: It should just be this: `$("#bgm").pause();` I would also suggest using the [HTML5 audio element](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) instead of `embed`.

Answer (score 0):

probably the [embed element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLEmbedElement) does not have the [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) interface which includes the pause() method. you can use the [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) [<audio>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) instead.

than: access the audio element directly from your click event handler.

```
$("#bgm").pause();
```

Comment: <audio autoplay loop id="bgm">
  <source src="../sound/frozen/10.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

Comment: are you using jquery? what does the console show after `console.log($('#bgm'), $('#bgm')[0] instanceof HTMLAudioElement);`

Comment: I don't dare to put that in my code now, I'll test it later if I dare to. can you tell me what's the code you wrote means? I'm not familiar with Jquery coding...(just a normal school student learning basic codes...)

Comment: it will output two things in the debug console. 1. if the reference to bgm works. 2. if bgm is a audio element. you may also put this into the debug console instead of your code.